# How can I add line breaks to the prompt in a google apps script dialogue box?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to provide a multi-line prompt message in a dialogue box using g-app script.

The resulting dialogue box would be:

---

Content of line 1.

Content of line 2.

Content of line 3.

Are you sure you want to continue?

YES / NO

---

Here's the code:

```
function testing() {

var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

const line1 = 'Content of line 1.';
const line2 = 'Content of line 2.';
const line3 = 'Content of line 3';

var dialogueMessage = [line1]+'\n'+
                [line2]+'\n'+
                [line3]

Logger.log(dialogueMessage); //Test message content. Looks correct, with three lines.

var result = ui.alert(
      dialogueMessage,
      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

}
```

The three separate lines appear when I log the message, but the dialogue box itself does not reflect any line breaks. Anyone know how I can add those breaks into the dialogue message?

Thx

Comment: You can separate the individual lines with delimiters like `/` and use String.split('/').join('\n'); Or use a custom dialog using a textarea.

Comment: I tried that, I think, when I concatenated the three line values into a variable (see var dialogueMessage). The delimiters (\n) seem to have worked when I log them out, but they don't seem to add any breaks when I run the dialogue box. Thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

  const line1 = 'Content of line 1.';
  const line2 = 'Content of line 2.';
  const line3 = 'Content of line 3';

  const dialogueMessage = `${line1}\n${line2}\n${line3}`

  const result = ui.alert(
        `${dialogueMessage}\n\nAre you sure you want to continue?`,
        ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

}
```

Your error was that you were not including your `dialogueMessage` correctly.

```
var result = ui.alert(
  dialogueMessage,
  'Are you sure you want to continue?',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

Corrected:

```
var result = ui.alert(
  '' + dialogueMessage + '\nAre you sure you want to continue?',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

See also:

- [Class Ui - Alert (prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt,-buttons)
- [MDN: Template Literals/Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)